# i.nightlights.intercalibration, Problem with running code

Tags: grass-gis

Problem with running i.nightlights.inter-calibration for the Elvidge (2014) model-coefficients.

Steps I have followed:

1.I have imported all the following layers individually:

> g.list type=raster

F101992
F101993
F101994
F121994
F121995
F121996
F121997
F121998
F121999
F141997
F141998
F141999
F142000
F142001
F142002
F142003
F152000
F152001
F152002
F152003
F152004
F152005
F152006
F152007
F162004
F162005
F162006
F162007
F162008
F162009
F182010
F182011
F182012
(Tue Jun 19 12:29:21 2018) Command finished (0 sec)

2. I have run the code on the dialog box of i.nightlights.intercalibration :
   [image]
3. For Some reason after running the code I got the following error message:
   [image]

What could be possibly going wrong?

Comment: Please see https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/grass-user/2018-June/078485.html. And, let us avoid cross-posting.